# animation-list is keeping memory in Ram

Tags: memory-management, android-animation

I am using animation-list for playing sequence of images. I could find that nearly 24MB i always kept in Ram by this approach.

Can any body advice me on how to get ride of memory in Ram after running animation sequence.

Using video to play animation or png sequence to play animation is good?

eg: animation-list png sequence xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >    

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ani_avatar_00016"
        android:duration="90" />            
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ani_avatar_00001"
        android:duration="90"/>    
    . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same problem.  There were to things we did to solve it.

First, we reduced the image size.  Try to have an image that is as small as possible.  We also tried video and that reduced the necessary memory allocation for each animation but we couldn't use this approach because we needed transparency.

Second is to make sure that you are using the same memory slot each time you load an animation. If you are not going to use several animations, then try to point a similar size object to the same memory address.

As far as I know, you can't control the garbage collector and ask for a memory space to be cleaned. So you can't wipe those MBs wether it is an animation or a PNG sequence.